# Tableau create a filter with several values in one option

Tags: tableau-api

I made a year over year percentage difference of some value in a pivot table. It works ugly: If Year=2018 is selected, the percentage is treaded as 100%. If I choose Year IN (2018, 2017), I can see the proper percentage diff for Year 2018 compared with 2017 treaded as 100%.

One idea I have is to create a radio filter that works like this:
If a user selects Year=2018, I want to show data for Year IN (2018, 2017). So actually two values are selected. The table pivot part with 2017 year is hidden though.
This should work for several Year options.

Is this possible?

Comment: Let me see if I can reframe your question: You have a table with year over year percent difference, but only want to show the selected year (while maintaining the table calculation)?

Comment: Right. And maintaining percentage differences as if the second year was there.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are all the years whose difference to the argument is at max one year. So if you choose 2018 as argument, you want to choose 2018 and 2017 from the data, if you choose 1997 you want 1997 and 1996.

So, create a parameter [Date Argument] for your target year. Then create the condition:
DATEDIFF('year',[Date],[Date Argument]) = 0 (OR 1) and add it to the view.

However, I believe what you are trying to do could be more easily achieved using a table calculation.

Comment: This worked, but produced an ugly date-calendar selector, when a simple year-selector would be easier to use.